# Approving a task directly from the dispform.aspx

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, list-form

I have a challenging requirement that I am trying to put my head around.  I have a SP Designer 2007 workflow for MOSS 2007 that has a series of approval tasks for each approver in the process.  Right now the workflow takes care of the email that will point the specific approver to the dispform.aspx of the ID.  It will also provide link to the simple approval task form that they will need to fill out.  This works fine.  However, the customer wants to have an approve link/button right on the dispform so they can view and approve in one shot.

In Designer they make it very easy for us to add look ups to the body of an email.  I don't know if I will be able to do this right from the dispform itself.  Is this achievable?  ANy thoughts on a prospective design would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, could you post the answer?